# MySQL Tier Pricing Structure

Tags: mysql

I am running into a problem that I need help working out. I'm not asking for anyone to provide code, just help me think this out into a way that will work for MySQL, as my MySQL skills are very, very limited.

We are trying to create a product database that can be called via PHP. I have no issue setting up the database EXCEPT for the tier pricing. Some products will start at 100, and have multiple price breaks to 5,000, while others may start at 10 and only got to 100. So, what will be the best way to execute this, that can be called from a PHP loop to insert it into the page as an HTML table.

My database so far is:

```
ProductID,
ProductName,
ProductImage,
ProductImage2,
ProductImage3,
ProductImage4,
ProductDescription,
ProductMisc,
ProductPricing (this is where I need help).
```

Do I need to create a separate table, that links by the ProuctID that has quantities and pricing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just have a separate pricing table. `priceID, itemID, min_quantity, max_quantity, price`. user asks for `x` items, lookup in the table for a record where `x BETWEEN min_quantity AND max_quantity` and theres your price.

Comment: But the prices are different for each quantity break, for example, 100 may be $10, but 250 might be $5. Thanks again!

Comment: exactly. so you'd have `($priceID, 'apples', 0, 100, $10.00)` and `($priceID, 'apples', 101, 250, $5.00)`: 0-100 apples, $10 each. 101-250 apples, $5.00 each.

Comment: Alright. So I could run this in a PHP loop, to render the results into an HTML table this way? I like it. If you want to post it as an answer, I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pricing table:

```
ItemQuantityPrices  (priceID, itemID, minQuantity, maxQuantity, price)
```

e.g.

```
Apples:
  1-100,   $5.00 each -> (1, apples, 1, 100, $5.00)
  101-250, $4.50 each -> (2, apples, 101, 250, $4.50)
  251-300, $4.00 each -> (3, apples, 251, 300, $4.00)
```

And your query would be, for something like "how much is an apple if I buy 252?":

```
SELECT price
FROM ItemQuantityPrices
WHERE itemID = 'apples'
    AND 252 BETWEEN minQuantity AND maxQuantity

--> $4.00
```

or, "how many apples do I have to buy if I want to pay $4.75 or less?"

```
SELECT minQuantity, maxQuantity
FROM ItemQuantityPrices
WHERE itemID = 'apples'
   AND price <= $4.75
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1

--> 101, 250
```